# child process owning the file used to redirect the std output of its parent process

Tags: windows, batch-file, file-io, command-line, stdout

Scenario
I have a batch file a.bat which below contains statements

```
A.exe >> a.txt
Test.exe >> a.txt
```

A.exe starts up another exe say b.exe (by _wpopen function) and returns. But after redirecting output of A.exe , ownership of a.txt seems to be transferred to b.exe. As test.exe cannot redirect its stdout to a.txt as b.exe is still running and still owns a.txt.

B.exe runs indefinitely, cannot wait for it to stop.
And also I cannot redirect the output to multiple files. As these exe executions are a part of installation setup, so logging should be continuous and must be done to a single file

Is there any possible solution to this scenario? I want the file a.text to be free after a.exe returns!

Comment: Depends how many `.exe`s you're running, for how long, and what you can change. How long do `a.exe` and its chained `b.exe` run before `Test.exe` joins in - could a simple delay sort it out? Could you rearrange things so that `a.exe` no longer starts `b.exe` but you call that one from the batch file instead?

Comment: Not tested, but i see not reason for it not to work. You can try to replace _wpopen with CreateProcess, explicitly defining the handles in the STARTUP_INFO structure. Or you can send each output to a separate file.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but both of your suggestions seems inapplicable to my context.Guys I have edited the question for more clarity.

Answer (score 0):

By putting the redirection on each line separately, you're requiring the command processor to reopen the file.  If another process still has the original handle to the file open, as in your scenario, that won't work.

Instead, redirect the output once for multiple commands, or for the entire batch file.  You can do this using the `call` command:

```
call :main >> a.txt
goto :eof

:main
A.exe
Test.exe
goto :eof
```

You could alternatively use brackets:

```
(
A.exe
Test.exe
) > test.txt
```

Or, if you only want *some* output to go to the file:

```
call :main 3>> a.txt
goto :eof

:main
A.exe >&3
Test.exe >&3
goto :eof
```

Keep in mind that until B.exe has exited, the log file will be held open, so the only way to write to it is to use an already existing handle.  (This assumes that you cannot modify A.exe; if you can, that's probably a better solution.)

It might also be possible to avoid the problem altogether like this:

```
A.exe > temp.txt
type temp.txt >> a.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, Nice workaround. But would be more elagant if there is any other solution that doesn't need batch file modification with labels as I want to keep the remaining batch file flow that does logging to the same file intact!