# File locking on Windows via command line

Tags: windows, winapi, command-line

Linux has a nice utility called [`flock`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/flock) for obtaining an exclusive lock on a file.  On Windows, a similar effect can be achieved using `LockFileEx` from the win32 API.  What command can I use at the Windows command prompt to lock and unlock files?

Caveat: the command should work on a clean install of Windows 7 -- I can't install any extra software.

Comment: LockFileEx API only locks a file for the lifetime of the process that invoked that function. What are you really trying to do?  If your goal is to just block files from being written to, you could type, "attrib +r filename" at the command prompt to make a file read only.

Comment: Being limited to the process lifetime is OK.  I'm trying to write a locking mechanism that works across a network share.

Comment: I'd like to use the win32 API directly, but that would mean adding a compilation step to our build process just for Windows, while our build system currently runs on Linux...

Comment: You can use MinGW-w64 to cross-compile Windows code on Linux; it should be available in your distribution. What distribution do you use?

Comment: By "at the command prompt" do you actually mean inside a batch file?

Comment: @andlabs I'll take a look at that!  Ubuntu.  I'm just worried that I might burn a week trying to get things set up.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Sort of.  I mean something that I could run using Node.js' [`child_process.exec`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback).

Comment: What file are you trying to lock?

Comment: I'm not too particular which file -- I just want to be able to create a file on a network drive and use it for locking (a "binary semaphore").

Comment: @user595228 late but there are MinGW-w64 packages in universe then.

Answer (score 1):

You can do simple locking from the command line using output redirection:

```
 runme -whatever 5>lockfile.txt
```

If another such command is already running, and using the same lock file, you will get the error message "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."

Comment: This is interesting, but it depends on the cmd shell, which opens the file with only read sharing. win-bash, in contrast, opens the file with both read and write sharing.

Comment: What does "5" mean in this context?

Comment: @eryksun: shouldn't be a problem, Node.js uses cmd.exe by default.

Comment: @selbie: in addition to the standard stream numbers (0 for standard input, 1 for standard output, and 2 for standard error) the batch processor supports custom numbers 3 through 9.  They can't be passed to child processes, so they are of [limited use](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22699070/886887).  The choice of 5 was arbitrary, any number from 3 through 9 would do.

Comment: The Windows file handle is inherited, which can be opened as a CRT file descriptor in the child using `open_osfhandle`. The catch is there's no built-in, simple way to discover and communicate the handle value. There are command line tools such as [Handle](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx), or you can write your own utility that calls undocumented APIs to enumerate the handle table. So let's just say there's no *good way* to pass them to child processes.

Comment: Nice, this might do the trick.  Crucially, though, I need a way to wait for the lock to be acquired before proceeding... I can kick off a subprocess running this command, but how can I tell if it actually succeeded in locking the file?

Comment: I get an error if it determines that the file is already locked, but how do I differentiate between "trying to obtain lock" and "successfully obtained lock"?  I could set a timeout for 100 ms and see if the process is still running at that point and assume that the lock was acquired, but that's prone to race conditions.

Comment: Why do you need to know?  If you run something else at the same time, whatever it is won't be protected by the lock anyway, because `runme -whatever` might exit first.

Comment: I thought you were suggesting something like `pause 5>lockfile.txt` that would keep the file locked until I kill the process.

Comment: Didn't think of that. :-) That would work, I suppose, if node.js allows you to do so.

Comment: It does :)  I'm left with the problem of detecting success though.  Btw, I looked into creating/deleting files as a locking mechanism originally, but supposedly "exclusive create" operations aren't reliably supported by Windows network shares...

Comment: If you use `pause 5>lockfile.txt` you should receive the "Press any key to continue" message if the lock is obtained and the "The process cannot..." message if it is not.

Comment: Good point.  Is that guaranteed to happen after the lock is established, though?

Comment: I'm going to do some more research into that.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yes, it doesn't run the command until after it has established the redirection.